# Remina doesn't ask for remote access enabled error while windows RDP showing this message

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

I just switched to windows 11 from linux for testing some applications. Whenever I tried to connect to remote server, I am having this [error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toiN9.jpg) but I never faced such issue with Remmina.

Comment: I mentioned windows 11, do I need to add more details?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.